# store string with entities in rails variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hey guys
when I store this string:

```
http://61.147.96.19/f4v/41/53283141.h264_2.f4v?10000&key=d7d7488b5dd4a35aac3e784cf4acb1a174ddc7&amp;playtype=1&amp;tk=2038443745&amp;brt=3&amp;id=tudou&amp;itemid=30165756&amp;fi=53283141&amp;sz=19354294
```

in a variable `@longurl`

and use it in a erb file

```
<%= @longurl %>
```

It doesn't work, when I check the source file in the browser :

```
http://61.147.96.19/f4v/41/53283141.h264_2.f4v?10000&amp;key=d7d7488b5dd4a35aac3e784cf4acb1a174ddc7&amp;amp;playtype=1&amp;amp;tk=2038443745&amp;amp;brt=3&amp;amp;id=tudou&amp;amp;itemid=30165756&amp;amp;fi=53283141&amp;amp;sz=19354294
```

and compare the differece, it add a `amp;` after each &amp, and I don't know how to avoid this.

BTW it seems `@url` is taken by the rails by default use, I can't save anything in the variable, Could anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Rails 3, try `<%= @longurl.html_safe %>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CGI::unescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CGI.html#M000533) to decode a URL-encoded string.

```
<%= CGI::unescape(@longurl) %>
```

For HTML entities, use `CGI::unescapeHTML`:

```
<%= CGI::unescapeHTML(@longurl) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want &
Read why here: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html

Is it 'breaking' the method in any other way, or just because it looks different?

If @url is used by Rails, use a different variable. It shouldn't be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1):

Before Rails 3, you used to have to code like this to make sure everything is HTML encoded:

```
<%= h @longurl %>
```

The `h` method would HTML encode your string. Now, everything is HTML encoded by default. If you don't want Rails to do this for you, we now have the `raw` method like this:

```
<%= raw @longurl %>
```

Read more about the `raw` method here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper.html#method-i-raw

or read about this change in the Rails 3 release notes
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#other-changes

Comment: Ya, the raw method just calls to_s.html_safe on what you pass in. So, if it's not already a string, raw will make sure it is before it calls html_safe.